# Why is there no article before "most importantly"?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I have a question about the expression "most importantly".

I think "most importantly" is used before the last item in a list to emphasize its importance. For example, in the sentence below, "most importantly" emphasizes "pack underwear".

> We need to pack socks and toothbrushes for the trip, but most
> importantly underwear.

source: [“Most important” vs “most importantly”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203917/most-important-vs-most-importantly)

In the quoted sentence, the items in the list are "pack socks", "pack toothbrushes" and "pack underwear", and adding "most importantly" shows that packing underwear is the most important. My question is, why do you say "most importantly", not "**the** most importantly"? As you are comparing multiple items, shouldn't you use the article before the superlative?

Comment: Perhaps the reason you think the article is "justified" is because you're assuming "most important/ly" modifies *[to] **pack** [whatever]*. But it doesn't - it modifies the main verb ***need***. That's to say, *We need to pack socks and toothbrushes for the trip, but **most importantly we need** to pack underwear.*

Comment: "the most important x" is a superlative. Adverbs can't be comparatives.

Comment: Which verb the adverb modifies doesn't change the fact the you don't use "the" with adverbs.  (See below, DJClayworth answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because "most importantly" is an adverb.**

It modifies the verb "need". The meaning is "You need to pack underwear most importantly".

Articles can only be applied to nouns.

If you wanted to specify specific underwear (rather than underwear in general) you would need to write:

> We need to pack socks and toothbrushes for the trip, but most importantly **the** underwear.

You should not confuse this with "most important" which is an adjective and thus modifies a noun.

> The most important thing to pack is underwear.